# unable to connect with Azure MySQL using c# .net

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, azure

I couldn't connect azure MYSQL in my c# program

and I got an error messaage "**using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: The connection string may not be right. Please visit portal for references.**"

I tried different connection string format but still couldn't solve it.
the curious point is I run the program in other pc, it works. But I run the program in pc always got this error.

ps: I tried `uid -> username@hotname` but still no luck, update the nuget mysql.data to the latest version and no use, dot net framework is 4.6.1

Could anyone help ? Thanks

Comment: What are those different connections string you have tried? When you run on another PC (and it works), is it trying to the same database on azure?

Answer (score 0):

You are required to follow the `<username@hostname>` format, whether you are doing it from `mysqlexe` client or `MySQL` workbench.
Though, you already did that then this issue might be related to the `MySQL Shell`.

Try the same connection info with the classic `mysql.exe` command line tool and it should work:

```
mysql.exe -u myuser@myserver -h myserver.mysql.database.azure.com -p
```

Take a look at [Connection Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-portal#get-connection-information) to understand more about how to connect to your `MySQL` server from various clients.

Hope it helps!